# Перенос сети на другую подсеть

Tags: сеть, switch, cisco, vlan, d-link

Есть подсеть вида 172.16.24.0 /24. Она раздаётся на все коммутаторы. Маркируется стандартным vlan'ом - 10. Нужно перевести коммутаторы на другую подсеть: 172.16.200.0 /27 c vlan 200. Возможно ли весь парк плавно перевести,прописав новые ip,и просто заменив 10 vlan на портах на 200?

Comment: *Она раздаётся на все коммутаторы.* Адреса, надеюсь, статические? *Маркируется стандартным vlan'ом - 10.* Надеюсь, tagged? *Нужно перевести коммутаторы на другую подсеть: 172.16.200.0 /27 c vlan 200.* А вилан-то управляющий нафига менять?

Comment: @Akina Конечно,везде статика. Да,tagged. Для стыка с другим офисом,чтобы образовать единую сеть

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для коммутаторов D-Link:

1. Сохраняем текущие конфигурации. Экспортируем к себе.
2. На все интерфейсы коммутаторов с управляющим VLAN vlanid=10 tagged добавляем новый VLAN vlanid=200 tagged.
3. На всех коммутаторах добавляем ещё один адрес (System - IP Interface) - в новом VLAN, в новой подсети, с включённым Admin State. При необходимости настраиваем для него остальные параметры доступа (AAA и прочее).
4. Подключаем PC только к новому VLAN с адресом только из новой подсети, проверяем, что все коммутаторы доступны и управляемы.
5. Сохраняем новые конфигурации. Экспортируем к себе.
6. Убираем из списка интерфейсов коммутаторов старые адреса.
7. Убираем с интерфейсов старые VLAN.
8. При необходимости переименуем новые VLAN и админ. интерфейсы.
9. Сохраняем новые конфигурации. Экспортируем к себе.

Аналогично (и параллельно по пунктам) поступаем и с оборудованием Cisco. Правило - при применении пункта к коммутатору этот пункт должен быть уже выполнен для всех коммутаторов позади него.

Comment: Т.е. создаю влан,назначаю ему статику,затем вешаю тегом на свободный порт,и смотрю,чтобы он получал адрес из этой подсети?

Comment: Я специально разделил на пункты. А Вы перемешиваете действия из пунктов. НЕТ. *создаю влан,назначаю ему статику* Адрес назначается внутреннему интерфейсу коммутатора. К VLAN адрес не имеет никакого отношения. Просто коммутатор пакеты, пришедшие на этот адрес не из того VLAN - проигнорирует как свои. Решит, что где-то есть узел с тем же адресом - и забродкастит пакет дальше. *смотрю,чтобы он получал адрес из этой подсети?* Адрес - статический! "получать" его и не нужно, и невозможно. *затем вешаю тегом на свободный порт* Какой "свободный"? написано же - ТОТ ЖЕ САМЫЙ...

Comment: А если тот же DES3026 не поддерживает create ipif,то тут тестить сразу в продакшн?

Comment: *DES3026* О боже, где Вы нашли такую древность? впрочем, чуть более свежие 3028P и 3052P у меня работают... *не поддерживает create ipif* Да, у него только `config ipif System ipaddress`, и адрес может быть единственным. Сочувствую... значит, в п. 3 вместо добавления нового адреса придётся перезаписывать, меняя старый. Ну и п. 6 теряет смысл и выпадает. Остальное всё так же. Значит, будете аккуратнее выполнять, чтобы не развалить сеть - ну это местами даже хорошо...

Comment: **Дополнительно. Важно.** Некоторые коммутаторы этой серии требуют, чтобы на магистральных портах (где тегованые виланы) обязательно присутствовал нетегованный дефолтный влан (vlanid=1) - если его отключить, трафик перестаёт ходить. Причём это в аппаратной части косяк - прошивка не влияет. Если vlan vlanid=1 name=default untagged есть на порте - ни в коем случае его не убирай!!! но не пускай в этот вилан клиентские порты.